# Standby shipping of my stuff from Thailand to Vietnam

Tags: luggage-storage, shipping, standby

I currently reside in Thailand with a student visa. In about 9 months, I would likely have to exit Thailand to try to make another Thailand student visa. If so, I would probably do it in Vietnam.

If I go to Vietnam to make another Thailand student visa I might have to stay there a few months until I could make a second Thailand student visa.

If I would have to stay in Vietnam a few months, most of my stuff would still be in my apartment in Thailand, yet I might not have around a friend that would have enough room to store store all my stuff or that I could count on to do that, and then sending me these stuff to Vietnam.

The stuff I have to move doesn't include furniture and weighs about 40 kilos.
About 15 Kilos of stuff I take by myself by one backpack, one backbag, and one sidebag. The other 25 kilos is likely to be large towels, dishes, and boxes and sacks filled with stuff, hence easy for shipment.

To solve the described possible problem, I was thinking to use some **"standby shipment"** service:
Before I leave to Vietnam I ask a company in Thailand to archive my stuff for 6 months; **if** I get another student visa, i comeback to Thailand and I take them back, **else**, the company will ship my stuff to my new address in Vietnam by notice.

**What is the name of such service and if there isn't what could be an essential substitute?**

---

If there isn't such a service, here are two alternatives respectively:

**The alternative I wouldn't do:**

If there isn't such as a service I might need to comeback to Thailand with a transit visa, ship all things to Vietnam by ThaiPost or some private international shipping company, and then come again to Vietnam but for me it would be very frustrating, financially disastrous and potentially harmful bureaucratically.

**The alternative I might do:**

I might send my stuff to my hotel address in Vietnam by *Thailand Post* and later send them back to Thailand by *Vietnam post* if I don't have to stay in Vietnam; I assume it will be cheaper than archiving by company in Thailand.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. I would search for a Thai business that does "storage and forwarding."

Comment: Is this really a Travel question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems it will be quite expensive according to [this thread titled "Moving household goods to Vietnam from BKK"](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/1090078-moving-household-goods-to-vietnam-from-bkk/?do=findComment&comment=14028832). In summary:
On April 10th, 2019 a person received a quote on 18-20 cubic meters of household goods from BKK to Da Nang for $7200 USD.
That quote didn't even cover storage:

> I just received a quote for 215K baht plus a 7% VAT for shipping 18-20 cubic meters of household goods from BKK to Da Nang. That is about $7200 USD just for shipping.  Add in the Vietnamese duties for electronics(40%) and furniture (10%) and the potential cost for customs inspections and I would have to seriously think about moving anything.  Too much paperwork and too many unknowns. If I was certain of the process and charges at the Vietnamese end it might be worth it but I need to do some more research.  28K baht solved the customs issue in Thailand so maybe a similar situation is available in Vietnam.

It seems to me that it is best for most people in Thailand to sell their stuff before moving throughout Asia.